# I cannot figure why this is not displaying scanned information correctly

Tags: c, pointers

I think certainly the problem is with address or pointers, but I cannot find it. Can someone describe the problem, or if feeling generous fix the code?

My problem is, it will not print what I input when prompted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getData(int* enterhour, int* enterminute, int* exitotalhour, int* exminute);
void rate(int exitotalhour, int exminute, int enterhour, int enterminute, int* totalhour, int* totalminute, int* round);
void charge(char* vehic, float* rate1, float* rate2, int enterhour);
void result(int* exitotalhour, int* exminute, int* enterhour, int* enterminute, int* totalhour, float* rate1, float* rate2, int* round, float* total);

int main(void)
{
    char vehic;
    int enterhour;
    int enterminute;
    int exitotalhour;
    int exminute;
    int totalhour;
    int totalminute;
    int round;

    float rate1;
    float rate2;
    float total;

    getData(&enterhour, &enterminute, &exitotalhour, &exminute);
    rate(exitotalhour, exminute, enterhour, enterminute, &totalhour, &totalminute, &round);
    charge(&vehic, &rate1, &rate2, enterhour);
    total= rate1 + rate2;
    result( &exitotalhour, &exminute, &enterhour, &enterminute, &totalhour, &rate1, &rate2, &round, &total);

    return 0;
}

void getData(int* enterhour, int* enterminute, int* exitotalhour, int* exminute)
{
    char v;

    printf("Enter c for car, b for bus, t for truck: ");
    scanf("%c", &v);
    printf("\nHour vehicle entered 0-24: ");
    scanf("%d", &enterhour);
    printf("\nMinute vehicle entered 0-60: ");
    scanf("%d", &enterminute);
    printf("\nHour vehicle exited 0-24: ");
    scanf("%d", &exitotalhour);
    printf("\nMinute vehicle exited 0-60: ");
    scanf("%d", &exminute);
    return;
}

void rate(int exitotalhour, int exminute, int enterhour, int enterminute, int* totalhour, int* totalminute, int* round)
{
    if(enterminute < exminute)
    {
        enterminute= enterminute + 60;
        exitotalhour= exitotalhour - 1;
    }

    *totalhour = enterhour - exitotalhour;
    *totalminute = enterminute - exminute;

    if ((*totalminute > 0 && *totalminute <= 60))
    {
        *totalhour = *totalhour + 1;
        *round = *totalminute * 0;
    }
    return;
}

void charge(char* vehic, float* rate1, float* rate2, int enterhour)
{
    switch (*vehic)
    {
        case 'c': if (enterhour <= 3)
        {
            *rate1 = 0.00;
            if (enterhour > 3)
            *rate2 = 1.50 * (float)(enterhour - 3);
        }
        break;

        case 't': if (enterhour <= 2)
        {
            *rate1 = 1.00 * (float)enterhour;
            if (enterhour > 2)
            *rate2 = 2.30 * (float)(enterhour - 2);
        }
        break;

        case 'b': if (enterhour <= 1)
        {
            *rate1 = 2.00 * (float)enterhour;
            if (enterhour > 1)
            *rate2 = 3.70 * (float)(enterhour - 1);
        }
        break;
    }
    return;
}

void result(int* exitotalhour, int* exminute, int* enterhour, int* enterminute, int* totalhour, float* rate1, float* rate2, int* round, float* total)
{
    printf("\n\t\t LOT CHARGE \t\t\n");
    printf("\nType of vehicle: Car or Bus or Truck");
    printf("\nTIME-IN\t\t %d:%d", enterhour, enterminute);
    printf("\nTIME-OUT\t\t %d:%d", exitotalhour, exminute);
    printf("\n\t\t\t --------");
    printf("\nPARKING TIME\t\t %d:%d", totalhour, round);
    printf("\n\t\t\t --------");
    *total= *rate1 + *rate2;
    printf("\nTOTAL CHARGE\t\t %4.2f\n\n", total);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code and post it directly in your question please.

Comment: And don't forget to strip out the irrelevant parts. (Good for debugging as well as presenting it to us.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your problem is in this function:

```
void getData(int* enterhour, int* enterminute, int* exitotalhour, int* exminute)
{
   char v;

   printf("Enter c for car, b for bus, t for truck: ");
   scanf("%c", &v);
   printf("\nHour vehicle entered 0-24: ");
   scanf("%d", &enterhour);
   printf("\nMinute vehicle entered 0-60: ");
   scanf("%d", &enterminute);
   printf("\nHour vehicle exited 0-24: ");
   scanf("%d", &exitotalhour);
   printf("\nMinute vehicle exited 0-60: ");
   scanf("%d", &exminute);
   return;
}
```

You are passing int pointers into the function, and then giving the addresses of those pointers to `scanf`. You should just pass the pointers themselves:

```
void getData(int* enterhour, int* enterminute, int* exitotalhour, int* exminute)
{
   char v;

   printf("Enter c for car, b for bus, t for truck: ");
   scanf("%c", &v);
   printf("\nHour vehicle entered 0-24: ");
   scanf("%d", enterhour);
   printf("\nMinute vehicle entered 0-60: ");
   scanf("%d", enterminute);
   printf("\nHour vehicle exited 0-24: ");
   scanf("%d", exitotalhour);
   printf("\nMinute vehicle exited 0-60: ");
   scanf("%d", exminute);
   return;
}
```

Comment: Ok this has improved the output vastly, but the total cost calculation is not displaying correctly, and the total time calculation seems to be weird. Thanks though, I'll keep editing around pointers!

Comment: Glad I could help, you should also check the answer posted by paislee, it looks like you have errors in your `printf` calls as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since the parameters to `result` are `int*`, don't you need to de-reference them in `printf`?

```
printf("\nTIME-IN\t\t %d:%d", *enterhour, *enterminute);
```